# Rails ... Can't access object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a bit confused here ... When I do (in a view):

`<% object = objects.where(:id => "xyz").take %>`

`<%= object %>`

returns `=> #<Object:0x007f455ef59dd0>`

but then:
`<%= object.id %>` returns an error:

*undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass*

I must me missing something (very obvious)?
thnx in advance for helping.

Comment: Are you reassigning `object` somewhere? Are you actually checking that `object` is not nil before using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `take` method returns nil if no record is found, so you don't have a record with "xyz".

If you're not sure that you have an object, you can do your attribute call with `try`

```
object.try(:id)
```

This will return the `id` if the object was found, or will return nil (without raising an exception) if the object is nil.

Comment: Strange? `object.try(:id)` gives me an id! Why then gives  `object.id`  a nil?

Comment: Has to be a typo.  `<%= object.id %>` always gives you the error?

Comment: Are you sure object always exists even with try? If you are looping through many objects, some of them might have ID and some with try just return nil.

Comment: You're right Steve! That's the one! Looping returns a nil sometimes. I stepped into this one before. Now I remember! Thnx!

Comment: I think you meant "You're right @midN" but glad it's sorted. :)